# Accessing GSM 03.38 Extended Character Set using ESC character

Tags: c, gsm

I´m programming a C application that communicates throuh serial port to a SIEMENS TC65 GSM Modem. I am able to correctly send SMS messages, but now I want to send some characters that are outside the default GSM 03.38 character set.

Please see: http://www.csoft.co.uk/sms/character_sets/gsm.htm

If I try to send, for instance, character `[`, this page tells me that I have to use `ESC` character followed by `<`. The problem is that the Modem is interpreting the `ESC` character and aborting the sending of the message, it is not reading the full message content.

Can anyone help me sending these characters that lay on the "extended" GSM 03.38 charset?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some incorrect characters in the table of your link. I suggest to download the orginal specification from 3GPP [here](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/0338.htm) for GSM and for the latest UICC [here](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/23038.htm). The UICC specification has included the euro symbol.

To access the Extension table, you need to add the escape control `0x1B` as follow:

```
 ^ : 0x1B 0x14
 { : 0x1B 0x28
 } : 0x1B 0x29
 \ : 0x1B 0x2F
 [ : 0x1B 0x3C
 ~ : 0x1B 0x3D
 ] : 0x1B 0x3E
 | : 0x1B 0x40
 € : 0x1B 0x65
 page break : 0x1B 0x0A
```

Example of use:

```
// [Hello]
byte[] text = new byte[] {0x1B, 0x3C, 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0x1B, 0x3E};
```

NOTES:

1. The ASCII code for 0-9, A-Z, a-z, space (some other characters) are similar as GSM default alphabet. For the rests, please look at the table
2. If the handset/mobile phone does not support the Extension Table character, it shall display them according to default table character (for example, euro will be shown as small 'e')
3. If you are using Arabic or Chinese, you cannot use GSM Default Alphabet and its extension table. Instead, use Unicode Character Set 2 (UCS-2)